# Transposed convolution as umpsampling in DCGAN

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, gan

I read several papers and articles where it is suggested that transposed convolution with 2 strides is better than upsampling then convolution.

However implementing such model with the transposed convolution resulted in heavy checkboard effect, where the whole generated image is just a pattern of squares and no learning takes place. How to properly implement it without totally messing up the generation? With the upsampling+convolution I got okay result but I want to improve my model. I am trying to generate images based on the CelebA dataset.

I use keras with tf and I used the following code:

```
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(256, 5, 2, padding='same'))

model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))



model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, 5, 2, padding='same'))

model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))



model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, 5, 2, padding='same'))

model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
```

Here I try to turn a 4x4 image into a 32x32. Later it will be turned into a 64x64 image with 1 or 3 channels depending on the image. However I get the following pattern always. Some tweaking usually leads to some other pattern but it does not really change:

[Checkboard effect](https://i.redd.it/oxefl4nwvfw21.png)

Thank you for your answers in advance

Answer (score 0):

This checkerboard effect arises due to taking sum of the overlapping regions during the transpose-convolution operation. Post convolution, in the output, the overlapping pixels have a higher magnitude than the surrounding pixels.
Try using a filter size of 4x4 along with a stride 2 transpose convolution. It may help to alleviate this problem.

For more information, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDPWywWRIRo) lecture from 30th minute.